# How to build Web Application using Ant?

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to build my web application using ant. But it is showing error -----

```
'dist-jar:
    [javac] P:\CM09\java\fmw-gpg\build.xml:28: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for re
table builds
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to P:\CM09\java\fmw-gpg\build\classes
    [javac] P:\CM09\java\fmw-gpg\src\com\alcoa\fmw\gpg\EncryptActionBean.java:105: illegal character: \64
    [javac]     @DefaultHandler
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] P:\CM09\java\fmw-gpg\src\com\alcoa\fmw\gpg\EncryptActionBean.java:113: <identifier> expected
    [javac] }
    [javac] ^
    [javac] P:\CM09\java\fmw-gpg\src\com\alcoa\fmw\gpg\ListActionBean.java:14: illegal character: \64
    [javac] @UrlBinding("/list")
    [javac] ^
    [javac] P:\CM09\java\fmw-gpg\src\com\alcoa\fmw\gpg\ListActionBean.java:24: illegal character: \64
    [javac]     @DefaultHandler
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] P:\CM09\java\fmw-gpg\src\com\alcoa\fmw\gpg\ListActionBean.java:28: <identifier> expected
    [javac] }
    [javac] ^
    [javac] 5 errors'
```

I have also checked that my web application .classpath file entries are :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/projects/aa-fmw-gpg/lib/commons-exec-1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/projects/aa-fmw-gpg/lib/commons-logging.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/projects/aa-fmw-gpg/lib/cos.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/projects/aa-fmw-gpg/lib/stripes.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Posting your `build.xml` might help

Comment: Looks like a compile error. `ListActionBean.java:28: expected } ` `EncryptActionBean.java:105: illegal character: \64`